# Display paginated list of custom entries

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I have an old hand-coded site for my book club that I would like to migrate to Drupal. Most of the content is static, but there is one part of the site that [lists our previous books and meetings](http://mostlyweeat.org/index.php?page=hist.php) (see link or image below). Note a few things:

- Text + images
- Toggle between "show all" and "show recommended"
- Although the current site has no pagination, that is desirable
- Desirable to have a way to import current list (e.g., via CSV)

What would be an appropriate mechanism to handle this in Drupal? I guess Drupal 7 is preferred, as that is the current version.

[image: screenshot of page described in the question]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were you, I'd proceed in that way:

- Export as CSV your existing data
- Install and configure your Drupal 7 (if you are new to Drupal, please read tutorials, documentation, and tutti quanti)
- Download [Feeds Import](https://www.drupal.org/project/feed_import) module that will allow you to create nodes with your CSV data
- Create a content-type "Book" with all the fields you need (they must match with the CSV fields).
- Configure Feeds Importer to import correctly your data (Read the [documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/2190315) to be sure)
- All your books will be automatically imported.
- Download [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) module that will allow you to make customs lists of books (sorted according to what you want). That also easy to manage pagination.

Good work and I hope it helped :-)

Comment: Thanks for the recipe. This looks imminently doable!

Comment: You're welcome. Don't forget to check as the right answer when you'll finish and if it was ok of course ;)